# Error in invalid inizialization of istream when passing as a reference

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm currently struggling with a compiler error related to ifstreams, and I would very much appreciate any assistance! Thank you in advance!

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const char EOS = '#';

bool end_of_sequence (ifstream &file)
{
    //Pre: EOS has not been read.
    //Post: whether or not the next character to read is EOS, in which case it is read.
    char test = file.get();
    bool ii_EOS  = (test == EOS);
    if (!ii_EOS) file.unget();
    return ii_EOS;
}

bool is_it_letter (char value_to_test)
{
    //Pre: value_to_test is an English character.
    //Post: whether or not value_to_test is a letter.
    return ((value_to_test >= 'a' && value_to_test <= 'z') || (value_to_test >= 'A' && value_to_test <= 'Z') || value_to_test == '·');
}

bool test_word (ifstream &file, char undesired)
{
    //Pre: file hasn't reached eof and is ready for a word to be read.
    //Post: whether or not [not (the first letter of the next word is undesired)].
    char first_letter = file.get();
    bool test = (first_letter != undesired && is_it_letter(first_letter));
    file.unget();
    return (!test); //I later found out test shouldn't be denied.
}

    void print_spaces (ifstream &file)
{
    //Pre: true.
    //Post: has read all the next non-letters in file and printed them onscreen.
    char current_space = ' ';
    while (!is_it_letter(current_space) && !end_of_sequence(file))
    {
        file.get(current_space);
        if (!is_it_letter(current_space) && current_space != EOS) cout << current_space;
    }
    file.unget();
}

void print_word (ifstream &file, bool printable)
{
    //Pre: true.
    //Post: if file has a word ready to be read, it is read. It is also printed onscreen if printable is true.
    char current_letter = file.get();
    while (is_it_letter(current_letter))
    {
        if (printable) cout << current_letter;
        file.get(current_letter);
    }
    file.unget();
}

int main ()
{
    //Declarations.
    string input;
    char undesired;

    //Input.
    cout << "INTRODUEIX EL NOM DEL FITXER:" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    ifstream mainfile(input.c_str());
    if (!mainfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "NO HEM TROBAT EL FITXER." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "INTRODUEIX UN CARACTER:" << endl;
    cin >> undesired;

    //Comput + output.
    cout << "TEXT RESULTANT D'ELIMINAR LES PARAULES QUE COMENCEN PER " << undesired << ":" << endl;
    while (!end_of_sequence(mainfile))
    {
        print_word(mainfile, test_word(mainfile,undesired));
        print_spaces(mainfile);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the function calling I'm getting this error in is:

```
print_word(mainfile, test_word(undesired));
```

(error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::ifstream& {aka std::basic_ifstream&}' from expression of type 'char'|)

In case it is relevant, the program itself is meant to print onscreen a sentence read from a file (with a non-physical end of sequence, being it '#') skipping the words starting by a previously inputted letter.

Because of the so-mentioned error, it doesn't get to compile. It might be a very dumb mistake, I'm still very new at programming. Thank you so much!

EDIT. I also realised (after I got to run it) that the returning for test_word shouldn't be denied according to the purpose of the program. I wrote it all by night and I knew it would have some dumb mistakes. Sorry!

Comment: `test_word` takes two arguments. Your invoke with `print_word(mainfile, test_word(undesired));` is only providing one.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Thank you so much WhozCraig!

Answer (score 2):

I think there's not sufficient information to be sure, since I have no idea what `mainfile` and `undesired` are. However, `test_word` required two argument and you're passing just one.  (Yet, there may be default arguments specified in a header file we don't see).

Comment: You're right! I provided the full code instead in order to be clearer. This was my first post and I'm not used, thank you so much! The problem was actually in passing just one argument to test_word.